# php/laravel - How to arrange arrays according to the highest number and number them

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.5

I have a table with marks of students in it. i have 2 record

```
student a = 90;
student b = 85;
```

I want to get the all the results for the total score of the students and then give the students positions in the class e.g

```
student a = 90; //first position
student b = 85; //second position
```

i have a column called position which is null after saving the total score of the students how can i check who is higher/lower and give them positions

Comment: You can use max function of mysql

Comment: You say you have a table, MySQL table?  HTML Table stored in an array?  How did you implement that?  Also users here will help you debug code.  If you post generic quesitons, you will get generic answers (ref. comments below).

Comment: ...but how do i assign class positions to the various students according to their total score

Comment: If it's a SQL table just use ORDER BY in your query to get them in the right order. Then print them out with a number next to each one (you can just use a for loop or something). Presumably position is temporary (until the next test) so no need to store it in the database, unless you want to keep historical records of positions at specific points in time.

Comment: @ADyson yes i want to store it in the MYSQL table so students can know what position they took in class

Comment: Like I said, no need to store it unless you want to keep historical records of positions at specific points in time, so they can see their scores for all tests through the year. Is that what you need? You didn't answer that part of my question. If not, you just can easily calculate the position each time you run the query. But also what have you tried to do so far? Sounds like you haven't even started. If you've got some code then please post it. No-one will give you a whole end-to-end solution like this just in one answer. If you've got something with a bug then we can fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you are using Laravel and you know how to use collections. This answer inspired from Adam Wathan's book.

```
$scores = collect([
    ['score' => 80, 'name' => 'a'],
    ['score' => 85, 'name' => 'b'],
    ['score' => 80, 'name' => 'k'],
    ['score' => 75, 'name' => 'h'],
    ['score' => 90, 'name' => 'w'],
    ['score' => 90, 'name' => 'v'],
    ['score' => 50, 'name' => 'r'],
    ['score' => 45, 'name' => 't'],
]);

function rankandscore($scores){

    return collect($scores)
        ->sortByDesc('score')
        ->zip(range(1, $scores->count()))
        ->map(function ($scoreAndRank){
            list($score, $rank) = $scoreAndRank;
            return array_merge($score, [
                'rank' => $rank
            ]);
        })
        ->groupBy('score')
        ->map(function ($tiedScores){
            $lowestRank = $tiedScores->pluck('rank')->min();
            return $tiedScores->map(function ($rankedScore) use ($lowestRank){
                return array_merge($rankedScore, [
                    'rank' => $lowestRank,
                ]);
            });

        })
        ->collapse()
        ->sortBy('rank');

}

$score = rankandscore($scores);
dd($score);

// will give output like this.
[
    ['score' => 90, 'name' => 'w', 'rank' => 1],
    ['score' => 90, 'name' => 'v', 'rank' => 1],
    ['score' => 85, 'name' => 'b', 'rank' => 3],
    ['score' => 80, 'name' => 'a', 'rank' => 4],
    ['score' => 80, 'name' => 'k', 'rank' => 4],
    ['score' => 75, 'name' => 'h', 'rank' => 6],
    ['score' => 50, 'name' => 'r', 'rank' => 7],
    ['score' => 45, 'name' => 't', 'rank' => 8],
]
```

You can use this function to modify according to your needs

> More Info https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-collections